# How to run IN condition in where clause in a List in flutter / Dart?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, where-clause

I'm trying to recovery data from a List that have a IN condition.
How do I perform something like that ??
Thanks

```
class Attractive
{
  String name;
  String type;
  Attractive({this.name,this.type});
}

List<Attractive> attraction=[];
attraction.add(name:"Everest",type:"mountain");
attraction.add(name:"Colorado",type:"river");
attraction.add(name:"Kilimanjaro",type:"mountain");
attraction.add(name:"Yellowstone",type:"park");

var listAttractive = attraction.where((element) => element.type in ("mountain","river"));
listAttractive.forEach((item){
print(item.name);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A better approach would be to use a `Set`

```
main() {
  List<Attractive> attraction = [];
  attraction.add(Attractive(name: "Everest", type: "mountain"));
  attraction.add(Attractive(name: "Colorado", type: "river"));
  attraction.add(Attractive(name: "Kilimanjaro", type: "mountain"));
  attraction.add(Attractive(name: "Yellowstone", type: "park"));

  Set<String> types = {"mountain", "river"};

  var listAttractive = attraction.where((element) => types.contains(element.type));
  listAttractive.forEach((item) {
    print(item.name);
  });
}

class Attractive {
  String name;
  String type;
  Attractive({required this.name, required this.type});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `in` keyword is used as way to loop over an `Iterable` in a for loop. For example:

```dart
for (int i in [1, 2, 3]) {
  print(i);
}
```

It is not a boolean test of whether a collection contains an item. You could use the `contains` method on a set containing all of the element types you want to check against.

```dart
class Attractive {
  String name;
  String type;
  Attractive({required this.name, required this.type});
}

void main() {
  List<Attractive> attraction = [];
  attraction.add(Attractive(name: "Everest", type: "mountain"));
  attraction.add(Attractive(name: "Colorado", type: "river"));
  attraction.add(Attractive(name: "Kilimanjaro", type: "mountain"));
  attraction.add(Attractive(name: "Yellowstone", type: "park"));

  var listAttractive = attraction
      .where((element) => {'mountain', 'river'}.contains(element.type));
  listAttractive.forEach((item) {
    print(item.name);
  });
}
```